# Use PHPDoc to find errors only

Tags: php, phpdoc

How can I run PHPDoc to get a list of errors without generating the full documentation?

I'm trying to write a plugin for my IDE which validates a file based on the error's generated by PHPDoc. However, I don't need it to go through the trouble of producing documentation.

I couldn't find an option in `phpdoc` for this. Alternatively, I could use PHPCodeSniffer to sniff our these violations. Are the rules for phpdoc available in sniffer form?

Example errors (I realize some of these are already available as sniffs but would prefer them to be in one place):

- No short description for class My_Class
- Argument $input is missing from the Docblock of myMethod()

Comment: you can run php -l file.php to find errors as well (lowercase L)

Comment: @ContextSwitch I'm not looking to lint-check my source. I'm looking for errors raised by PHPDoc when it generates documentation. Things like "You're missing a param here", not `Syntax Error: Unexpected $end`

Comment: I'm not aware of any way for phpDocumentor to do this.  It accumulates that error listing as it parses the code for doc generation.  You might consider submitting a Github issue to request that capability as a new feature, as it might very well be easy for @mvriel to implement.

Answer (score 2):

[According to phpdoc.org](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/validating-documentation-in-your-code.html), you can generate a checklist of errors with the following command:

```
$ phpdoc -d [SOURCE] -t [TARGET] --template checkstyle
```

[That link](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/validating-documentation-in-your-code.html) also provides several alternative methods of doing this as well.

Comment: The link you provided is dead now.